# How do I change a dodged bar graph so the bars follow a selected color pattern,not a gradient, and how to keep bars from changing positions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[csv file I'm working with](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RCygUzKkyra2Mr_hNNPtPb2rLeyleZNE)

***I'm relatively new to R and coding in general.  I have done a bit of Googling and trial and error to figure out my mistakes/solve my issues but to no avail.  Help is greatly appreciated.

For the file above, I'm creating a dodged bar graph to show each quarter from 2017-2020.  However, it produces a gradient and I want individual colors.  For example, I want all Q1s to be red.  All Q2s to be green, etc. I tried using scale_fill_manual() but had no luck.
[gradient result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dY0u.jpg)

```
testplot1<-ggplot(test, aes(x=Year, y=Sales, fill=Sales))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity", aes(group=Q))+
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Sales",
       title="Sales Year-Over-Year",
       subtitles = "Test")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
        plot.title= element_text(face="bold", size=14, color = "black", hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  geom_text(aes(label=dollar(Sales)), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.8, color = "black",
            size = 2,position = position_dodge2(width = 1),inherit.aes = TRUE)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar_format(prefix="$"), expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-200000,800000))
testplot1
```

I tried setting the fill to as.factor(Sales), but then it changes the order of the 2020 quarters.  Any help is appreciated.
[various colors and rearranged 2020 quarters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUrqn.jpg)

```
testplot<-ggplot(test, aes(x=Year, y=Sales, fill=as.factor(Sales)))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity", aes(group=Q))+
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Sales",
       title="Sales Year-Over-Year",
       subtitles = "Test")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
        plot.title= element_text(face="bold", size=14, color = "black", hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  geom_text(aes(label=dollar(Sales)), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.8, color = "black",
            size = 2,position = position_dodge2(width = 1),inherit.aes = TRUE)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar_format(prefix="$"), expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-200000,800000))
testplot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be tricky when you're trying to color a variable that you know is a categorical variable (the quarter) but that is listed as a number and thus that R interprets as a continuous variable. You can get around that by coding it as a factor like this:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=Year, y=Sales, fill=as.factor(Q)))+
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity") +
      labs(x = "Year", y = "Sales",
           title="Sales Year-Over-Year",
           subtitles = "Test") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "gray")) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
            plot.title= element_text(face="bold", size=14, color = "black", hjust = 0.5),
            plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
      theme(legend.position = "none")+
      geom_text(aes(label=dollar(Sales)), hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.8, color = "black",
                size = 2, position = position_dodge2(width = 1),
                inherit.aes = TRUE) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar_format(prefix="$"), 
                         expand = c(0,0), limits = c(-200000,800000))
```

The critical bit is the `fill = as.factor(Q)`.

Comment: Thank you, shirewoman2.  This is helpful.  I didn't think to change the fill to Q instead of Sales.  Slowly but surely I'm learning.

Comment: Great! Glad it was useful, @Josh. If I've answered your question, please mark it as answered.